# Is boost::multi_index_container consecutively stored in memory?

Tags: c++, boost, collections, boost-multi-index

I'm looking for a consecutive data structure for fast iteration times, combined with fast random access through a key. Moreover, I need to efficiently get back the key from an index. Currently, I use a combination of different collections from the standard library.

```
std::vector<Value> values;
std::unordered_map<Key, size_t> indices;
std::unordered_map<size_t, Key> keys;
```

This works, but it requires some glue code and may be not as fast as possible. It seems like `boost::multi_index_container` does exactly what I need. However, does it store values in memory consecutively?

Comment: Have you considered storing an `std::pair<Key, Value>` in the vector, to eliminate the Map `keys`? You could provide custom iterators over keys and over values in that case,

Comment: I reckon that's an implementation detail. If you must know, you can look at the docs when they describe the complexity guarantees. Also, you can glean some inside info from the performance tests. Now, obviously, you _could_ just read the source

Comment: @NicholasM That wouldn't give me log(n) time to find the key from a vector index. I consider `boost::bimap` to combine `indices` and `keys`, however.

Comment: @danijar accessing a vector element by index is a constant-time operation. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.MultiIndex does *not* store values contiguously, though its random-access indices provide vector-like access that might be performant enough for your needs.